# How do I make elements collide with fixed element?

Tags: html, css, css-position

How do I make a fixed element push other elements to the side when they overlap?

I don't want this:
[image]

Or this:
[image]

I want this:
[image]

I want to know how to make the elements collide or push so that I can easily align the elements without having to position them pixel by pixel.

Edit: I tried positioning a `div` to be fixed and displaying it as a block, but other elements were still overlapping it. Is it even possible to push elements away from a fixed element?

Comment: Take a look to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70941384/14807111

Comment: Fixed positioning doesn't collide with any other layout elements. That is just what it does. You will need JavaScript to move the other elements in the page by the width of the fixed element if that is your layout choice.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it even possible to push elements away from a fixed element?

I would say no. Not with this concept.

I can think of two solutions that I would not recommend.

1. Implement it with an iframe. But I would not recommend that.
2. Using JS to read out the width and assign it to the neighbouring element.

I updated my question after i got a good hint. For this example i added body height 200vh; that you can scroll down to see like it works.

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
.verti {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  top: 8px; 
}

.hori {
  background: green;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;  
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="hori"></div>
  <div class="verti"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried using float? I'm pretty new to all this but this is what I got:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="fixed">
            <p class="center-text white">Fixed <br>Element</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="not-fixed">
            <p class="center-text white">Not Fixed Element</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <style>
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family:arial;
        }

        .center-text {
            text-align:center;
            position:relative;
            top:45%;
        }

        .white {
            color:white;
        }

        #container {
            margin:10px;
            width:700px;
            height:700px;
        }

        #fixed {
            background-color:red;
            position:fixed;
            width:200px;
            height:500px;
        }

        #not-fixed {
            position:relative;
            background-color:green;
            width:500px;
            height:200px;
            float:right;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to help, but I'm looking for a way for the fixed element to collide with other elements. Basically, I'm looking for a lazy way to position elements next to a fixed element so that the non-fixed element does not go behind or in front of the fixed element. If my question is confusing then don't worry about it, I'll just use the traditional way of positioning elements. Thanks Anyway! Your alternative is also helpful!